# How to center a large equation on the page?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, adjustbox

I have the following definition that I am attempting to type into my Latex document. I've attempted to place it both in a \centerline{...} and \adjustbox{center}{...}, but I keep getting errors about things not being in math mode despite the outter \[ ... \].

```
\adjustbox{center}{
    \[\\
        \mathbf{M}_{a}^{b}(p) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
            \emptyset   
            &   (\floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1) = 0 \\
            
            p \times \left\{
                \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}}, \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1,   
                ..., 
                \floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - 1, \floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}}
            \right\}    
            &   otherwise \\
        \end{array}\right\}
    \]
}
```

Please advise on the proper way to go about centering a long defition like this in Latex with math-mode.

Comment: You can't use ``\\`` inside `\[...\]` to begin with.

Comment: @egreg really? I use that all over the place and TexLive doesn't complain. I get the expected effect

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams, please prove your claim with some example! I like to see this ...

Comment: @Zarko. Let me clarify my usage (which is all I'm doing above): I use it where there is an end of line already within the `\[...\]`. For instance, at the very end, just before `\]` or I might add two `\\ ` at the end of a line in the context of a `begin{array}...end{array}`, etc. This causes an extra line to appear between whatever that last line was and the next line - whether the next line is within the `\[...\]` or outside of it. I'm not saying that `\\ ` always causes a break - but there are plenty of valid cases where it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You *might* use `adjustbox` inside `\[...\]`, but the result is really awful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\[
\adjustbox{center}{$
\mathbf{M}_{a}^{b}(p) =
\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
  \emptyset & (\floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1) = 0 \\
  p \times \left\{
                \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}}, \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1,   
                \dots, 
                \floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - 1, \floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}}
            \right\}    
  &   \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right\}$}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The formula is decidedly unreadable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
We can define
$\mathbf{M}_{a}^{b}(p) = \emptyset$
when $(\floor{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - \ceil{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1) = 0$ and
\[\textstyle
\mathbf{M}_{a}^{b}(p)=
p \times \left\{
    \ceil*{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}}, \ceil*{\frac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1,   
    \dots, 
    \floor*{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - 1, \floor*{\frac{\max(a, b)}{p}}
\right\}
\]
otherwise. \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say it is unreadable, just a tad bulky. I can always reduce the right-hand side via a variable or the like. Unfortunately, nesting it this way doesn't resolve the errors from TexLive. I don't know, however, if that is an oddity of TexLive or not - I'm new to LaTeX. I still see errors about not being about to use the various commands like \mathbf unless it's in math-mode. But +1 for the alternative formatting suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

With use of `\medmath` and `\mfrac` of `nccmath` package and `cases` of `mathtools` package you can reduce equation size for about 20%:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
    \[\medmath{
\mathbf{M}_{a}^{b}(p) =
    \begin{dcases}
\emptyset   & \biggl(\floor*{\mfrac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - 
                        \ceil*{\mfrac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1\biggr) = 0 \\[1ex]
    \begin{multlined}
p \times \biggl\{\ceil*{\mfrac{\min(a, b)}{p}},
                 \ceil*{\mfrac{\min(a, b)}{p}} + 1,\dotsc, \\
    \dotsc,\floor*{\mfrac{\max(a, b)}{p}} - 1, \floor*{\mfrac{\max(a, b)}{p}}\Biggr\}
    \end{multlined}
            &   \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}}
\]
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh nice, I'll give that a try :)